# Passing a Resource to an Activity via an Intent

Tags: android

I have been trying for hours to pass a resource from one Activity to another via an Intent.

Here is the code from my 'Source' Activity:

```
           Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Activity3.class);

            int res = R.raw.voicefile;

           myIntent = myIntent.putExtra("soundfile", res);

            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

As you can see, I have a file called voicefile in my raw folder and I am setting res equal to it and passing it with my intent. (I am assuming it is of type int)

In my receiving Activity, I have:

```
    Intent sender=getIntent();
    int file=sender.getExtras().getInt("soundfile");
```

At this point I was HOPING that file would equal R.raw.voicefile in my destination Activity and that I could use my variable 'file' in my MediaPlayer call as such:

```
          MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), file).start();
```

versus:

```
          MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.voicefile).start();
```

My problem is whenever I click the button from my Source Activity that launches my Destination Activity, I get a Force Close.

Do you experts see anything glaringly wrong with my code?

Comment: What's the error? The log should have detailed information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
int file=sender.getIntExtra("soundfile", 0);
```

I think `Intent.getExtras()` assumes you have used a `Bundle` to map your extras in the `Intent`, which you have not.